# Prediction with LSTM text generator

Tags: python, theano, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I'm using the [`lstm_text_generation`](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_text_generation.py) code of Keras in order to generate text.

I want to run it in prediction mode on a test file I have after the training has finished. For example, I want to calculate the percentage of times the prediction with highest probability is the same as the expected target.

How should I do that?

Comment: What did you try so far? The obvious thing is using `model.predict`.